# Get div height using jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have a table which has many rows and 3 columns. Each column has `div` inside. I want to get the height of the `div` in the 2nd column.
I gave jQuery as under:

```
$('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div').height(); // works good, returns height of first rows div
```

Now, I want to run this in a loop so get the height of `div` present in all rows in 2nd column. So I wrote planned this code:

```
var count = $('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div').length;
    $('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div')[0]; //
    $('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div')[1]; // and so on in a loop
```

But this returns error

```
$('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div')[0]; // Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].height is not a function
```

**P.S:** Newbie to jQuery here. Pardon my foolish mistakes.

Comment: Could you include a [MRE] that includes the HTML that this jQuery is being applied to please? It would make it much easier for us to help :)

Comment: You can use the jQuery `.each` function (see [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)). So, it would be something like `$('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div').each(function(i, item) { var height = $(item).height(); });` When you call something like `$('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div')[0]` that returns the DOM element, not a jQuery object - which is why you get an error calling a jQuery function `.height()`

Comment: @FluffyKitten Pls see demo link

Comment: I'd just posted an answer before I saw your new codepen :) Is my answer what you were looking for (you did mention wanting to loop through the elements) or do you need to get one specific element at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the values returned from the jQuery selector are not an array, so you cannot loop through them like an array. You need to use the `each()` jQuery function to do this.

You can do this like follows:

```
$('#elementId tbody tr td.elment-class-2 div').each(function(i, ) { 
    divHeight = $(divToCheck).height(); 
});
```

The `i` is the index of the
(Note also that you are unlikely to need such specificity in your selector - it can make the code less reusable and more difficult to maintain)

Without your original HTML, I can only show you a generic example of this working below:

```js
$('tr div').each(function(i, divToCheck) {
  divHeight = $(divToCheck).height();
  console.log("Div "+ i + " height = "+ divHeight);
});
```

```css
td { border:1px solid grey;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>hello</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div style="height:30px;">hello </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="font-size:20px">hello</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your CodePen and it seems that for variable `ht` there is a typo, the class needs to be next to the TD ie `td.elmCls` and for the second part here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var ht = $('table tbody tr td.elmCls').height();
  console.log(ht)

  var divs = $('tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2) div');
  divs.each(function(index, elem) {
   console.log(elem.innerText);
   var height = $(elem).height();
   console.log(height);
  });
});
```

The reason why you see that error is because when you try to get an object via `$()` method it will initially return a jQuery object. When you then use `[0]` on the object like `$('td.elmCls')[0]` you then get back a native Javascript node/element. That node does not have a `height()` method on it and this is why you get that error.

You resolve this by using the `.each(function(index, element){ [code-here]})` method and then simply printing `element.innerText` out to the console.

Comment: Yes, and other way would be to convert that javascript node/element to jQuery object using `$(divs [0])` and then invoke `height()` on it, right ?

Comment: In the reply I posted I've added an update. While in the ```each``` loop you can convert a regular node to a jQuery object to be able to use ```.height()``` using this code ```var height = $(elem).height();```